# Connecting two network (two router with both dhcp server enabled)

Tags: networking, routing, wireless-bridge

Im new to networking.

I have 2 separate network that spans across 2 building, only one of the network has access to internet.

My question is how do i get those two connected while keeping both dhcp servers active, right now i have made them work using a bridge, but this is not the set up im looking for

Refer to the image [image]

So i need to get network a's router and network b's router connected without messing up the dhcp server on both router, while letting network b have access to network a's internet. and to make the computers on both netwok not detect each other (network a's computers should not be able to see network b's computer), and i need them to be connected over wifi

Answer (score 2):

DHCP requests don't cross routers unless there is a DHCP relay agent. So in your case, the PCs in one building will get their IP from their local router, and the PCs in the second building will get their IP from their own local router.

If you configure the gateway IP correctly for the dhcp clients, then all requests to IP addresses outside of their local IP subnet will route through their own local gateway, which is their router.

If you disable the bridging and just connect up the routers and configure the appropriate routes on them, then you can get router b to send any requests outside of it's local subnet to router a. Router a will send any requests to the internet out through it's internet interface. Depending on the routers, you can configure Access Control Lists and prevent the two subnets from communicating with each other.

Any wireless clients connecting to the WiFi access point should get IP addresses valid for that subnet and will behave like any other PCs in that subnet.

-Sysadmin Guy